# How to submit checked input?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am using `vuejs v.2`, In my data structure I have products and keywords
they have many-to-many relationship. To attach keywords to product I have list of keyword's checkbox and when user submit only checked keyword should be attach to product

```
<div class="col-md-6" v-for="keyword in keywords">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />
                {{ keyword.name }}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I can not bind `keyword.id` as value (`v-bind:value`).

I just want to submit checked keyword ids to server
Please show me the correct way

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake you might be doing is not using v-model with an array data variable, following is working code:

vue component:

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: function(){
        return {
        keywords: [
            {name: 'key1', id: 1 },
          {name: 'key2', id: 2 },
          {name: 'key3', id: 3 }
        ],
        checked: []
      };
    }
})
```

and in HTML:

```
<div id="demo">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label v-for="keyword in keywords">
            <input type="checkbox" :id="keyword.name" v-bind:value="keyword.id"  v-model="checked"/>
                {{ keyword.name }}        
                <br>
        </label>
        <br>
        checked value: {{checked}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fbo0qmkd/)